# How to install joomla on localhost:8080?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am running IIS and WAMP on same PC. The IIS is running on localhost and Wamp is running on localhost:8080. Now the problem is that when i strat to install joomla in WAMP, the installation is not proceeding from database configuration step. I enter the host name as localhost:8080 on database configuration step.

Comment: Port 8080 is the port your webserver is listening on... not your database server. You probably shouldn't have to change the default port for MySQL (from memory something approximately like 5460)

Comment: But in Normal condition the host name for database configuration is localhost in joomla.

Comment: Localhost is default in joomla, 8080 is just for your webserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill with `localhost` without port number, it did on my local. I also use IIS and XAMPP (8080).